# couchdb is not replying to commands

Tags: node.js, couchdb

first off, it was a major pain to install couchdb on ubuntu but one of the ways finally works (apparently) but i dont have an account if that matters. Still runs. So, im going through the node.js the right way book and when i type in commands this is what i get. nothing. Apache CouchDB 1.6.1

```
(LogLevel=info) is starting.
Apache CouchDB has started. Time to relax.
[info] [<0.32.0>] Apache CouchDB has started on http://127.0.0.1:5984/
./dbcli.js
./dbcli.js GET books
curl http://127.0.0.:5984/
```

and heres the program

```
    #!/usr/bin/env node --harmony
const
request = require('request'),
options = {
method: process.argv[2] || 'GET',
url: 'http://localhost:5984/' + (process.argv[3] || '')
};
request(options, function(err, res, body) {
if (err) {
throw Error(err);
} else {
console.log(res.statusCode, JSON.parse(body));
}
});
```

as you can see ive tryed a few with no luck. Whats the issue? Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: no, i didint get any errors, just what you see

Comment: What's in `statusCode` and what contains `body`?

Comment: that code in the program is all there is. after that it tells me to chmod +x dblci.js than run the ./dbcli.js and it should respond 200 { couchdb: 'Welcome', version: '1.2.1' } but i get no reply instead. grrr. so im thinking maybe its either the way ive installed couchdb or that i dont have an account or that the folder/files arent connecting with couchdb since they arent in the same area? the file is in ryan/Documents/code/databases/dbcli.js. I guess couchdb is supposed to be able to get files anywhere on your computer? this should be trivial, maybe its that i dont have a couchdb account?

Comment: if youd like i could give you the link to the pdf, its on free it ebooks.com or something. page 68

Comment: https://it-ebooks.info/book/3747/

Comment: i just want to get on with the last half of this book, bah

Comment: does anyone know?????

Comment: o great, looks like i wont be learning anymore node from this book.... yaaaay!

Comment: When you issue an HTTP GET request to the server’s root ( / ), CouchDB gives
you a welcome message. nope, not getting that.

Comment: First of all, stop behaving as a retard, please. With this attitude, nobody will help you. What does it mean "*that code in the program is all there is*"? What status code does your script print? Which branch of condition is executed, `if` or `else`?

Comment: Also IP address in your curl command is invalid (`curl http://127.0.0.:5984/`), try the right one: `curl http://127.0.0.1:5984/`.

Comment: yes, your right. That curl command gave no reply as well. This is the link i used to install couchdb if the info matters https://github.com/pixelpark/ppnet/wiki/Install-CouchDB-1.6.1-on-Ubuntu-14.04 but once i reached this line i got an error so stopped there chown -R couchdb: /var/lib/couchdb /var/log/couchdb. All the previous stuff got me couchdb installed.

Comment: So how did you execute CouchDB server? (it's after the command you stopped on). I would try to do all operations as described first.

Comment: i type sudo couchdb to start her up. o yes, and one thing i didnt mention is that on the line before chown at the end useradd -d /var/lib/couchdb couchdb i replace couchdb at end with ryan. maybe i have to make a change to the chown command as well? im going to remove and purge couchdb and start it over again and let you know.

Comment: Wait, so you didn't actually created an user for CouchDB, you just created some account for yourself? Why? How do you expect CouchDB should work without an own user?

Comment: idk man. im a noob to couchdb and just recently started with node.js. but i do have knowledge of basic unx/linux commands. I just know that when i entered that line work for word it gave me an error and couchdb at the end was the problem i believe, bah. ill redo the steps process and let you know the error i get. brb

Comment: funny thing is... when i remove and purge couchdb it says its not installed lol.... so why the hell can i get it to run. seems funny, just sayin, brb

Comment: But you did mistake in basic *nix/linux command actually, that's not related to CouchDB. CouchDB need it's own user so it can access it's own files. How it could know that it should use some user named "ryan"? That doesn't make a sense to me. The most important is to **read and understand error messages**, if there are any.

Comment: Also why do you actually compile it? You wrote you're a noob. Compiling things is rather for power users. Just install it using a package manager. It does everything for you (creating directories, user(s), manage permissions, init scripts etc.). How did you try to uninstall it?

Comment: `apt-get install couchdb`

Comment: Well it doesn't surprise me at all, that you tried to compile and install it manually, actually did only half of installation steps (and with errors and changes) and than was wondering, that it doesn't work :)

Comment: k, have the first issue everything before works. ryan@Ryan:/tmp$ tar xvzf apache-couchdb-*
tar (child): apache-couchdb-1.6.1: Cannot read: Is a directory
tar (child): At beginning of tape, quitting now
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: couchdb : Depends: couchdb-bin (>= 1.6.1-0ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. that error is why im trying this method. ^^sudo apt-get install couchdb

Comment: OMG. First of all, don't ask about every common issue before you try at least minimum of your own effort to solve problems. Second, you already broke your package managing system. https://www.google.com/search?q=apt-get+install+"Unable+to+correct+problems%2C+you+have+held+broken+packages"

Comment: i was looking for literally 3 hours last night on this topic. i was actually to lazy to sign up for this site but am forced to. I downloaded erlang seperately since it was an "unmet dependency witch the apt-get install couchdb command gave me and couchdb : Depends: couchdb-bin (>= 1.6.1-0ubuntu5). I searched for 3 hours on the solution and there was none which i was astonished at. So you're saying ive broken my package managing system? hmm that doesnt sound good. Whats the fix if i might ask?

Comment: Fix is to copy your error message to Google, as I did for you in my previous comment, and read first few (most probably only the very first) link(s).

Comment: this is what i get from the first link. i run sudo apt-get update than sudo aptitude -f install couchdbThe following packages have unmet dependencies:couchdb-bin:Depends: erlang-abi-15.b which is a virtual packageThe following actions will resolve these dependencies:Keep the following packages at their current version:1)couchdb [Not Installed]  2)     couchdb-bin [Not Installed] Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] yNo packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.Need to get 0 B of archives.Afterunpacking 0 B will be used.

Comment: ofcourse before that is a long list of ign, node, and lib things  getting removed, "The following packages will be REMOVED:" and says The following NEW packages will be installed:
  couchdb couchdb-bin{ab} couchdb-common{a}
why im confused now friend........? ;) and im just a noob so

Comment: Does it mean you don't have any held broken package?

Comment: and this at the end is what really confuses me....No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded. and i can still run couchdb the same as before btw, not replying to commands.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

Comment: Why? It won't install anything because, as it said, you have unmet dependencies because of held broken packages. Once more my question: Does it mean you don't have any held broken package?

Comment: this command says nothing about held broken packages. just the unmet dependency erlang. o i c. ill google again 1 sec

Comment: OMG!!1! It's on first link in Google search I sent you: `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`

Comment: yes i tryed that command and it gives me no response so i guess i have no broken packages ^Cryan@Ryan:~/Documents/code/databases$ dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
ryan@Ryan:~/Documents/code/databases$ 
thats what im also confused about. yes sorry, i forgot to mention i tryed that command and it gave me nothing, sorry friend

Comment: OK, than try what describes another user: `sudo apt-get autoremove`. And try it without me saying you to do so. Use your own brain, unless you're 5 years old and you need someone to hold your hand.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded. now what :). now i try the sudo apt-get install couchdb?

Comment: Sorry, but this is really crazy. Internet is full of advices, what you have to do. All you have to do is to copy & paste your errors / problems to Google, click usually on the first link, read what's there and try it. Nobody will do it for you. I'm repeating myself. Just do 10 search; 20 read; 30 try; 40 if success go to 50 else go to 10; 50 profit. Repeat until success.

Comment: My previous comment once more: OK, than try what describes another user: sudo apt-get autoremove. And try it without me saying you to do so. Use your own brain, unless you're 5 years old and you need someone to hold your hand

Comment: my friend. I copied and pasted the errors i was getting, the unmet dependiences, broken errors etc  for hours last night and there still seems to be no solution. still have this problem after your command :(. couchdb : Depends: couchdb-bin (>= 1.6.1-0ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. i thought we found i had no held borken packages...?

Comment: Does it mean `apt-get autoremove` didn't help?

Comment: lol. ive been playing games for the last 25 years of my life... done with that, its a waste. time to do something important and be successful. this sure as hell aint gonna stop me. this aint my fault, you cant figure it out either bro bro ;)

Comment: apparently not if its supposed to fix broken held packages. ryan@Ryan:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.

Comment: so whats the next option?

Comment: Try to execute `apt-get install couchdb` again.

Comment: Sorry, I have to go to bed, it's 3 AM here. I can't search copy & paste everything for you. Read it yourself. This is real waste of time.

Comment: yes, friend. I appreciate your time. the apt get install couchdb command gives me Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 couchdb : Depends: couchdb-bin (>= 1.6.1-0ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Last hint: it's possible, that you still have that crippled previous installation of CouchDB, therefore it's not possible to install it using package manager. Try to clean it first. Search Google. Good luck!

Comment: yes, im checking out this help, looks in depth. http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa  see ya later

Comment: yup so after i tryed all the commands it still has the same broken package and couchdb-bin depenendency. says as a last resort Finally, if all else fails, you can attempt to satisfy the dependencies yourself, either by finding and installing the necessary packages, or by installing them from source and then creating “deb” packages for them. And as i told you before i was sort of already on top of this idea trying to install erlang which i did but never was successful at finding couchdb-bin (>= 1.6.1-0ubuntu5). My circumstance is rare, apparently.

Comment: another odd thing is that i already have couchdb installed apparently, which is the dependency. is this weird?                                                          ryan@Ryan:~$ dpkg -l | grep couch
rc  couchdb-bin                                           1.6.1-0ubuntu5                                      amd64        RESTful document oriented database yet, when i do dpkg --purge --force-all couchdb i get dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove couchdb which isn't installed

Comment: at this point i think the best thing to do is go back to the installation process i stopped short on. so, here is the error i get when typing the chown command i was telling about earlier. ryan@Ryan:~$ chown -R couchdb: /var/lib/couchdb /var/log/couchdb and, repeating myself from before, i typed in all code before this and everything went perfectly. This is the stumbling block.
chown: cannot access ‘/var/lib/couchdb’: No such file or directory
chown: cannot access ‘/var/log/couchdb’: No such file or directory  https://github.com/pixelpark/ppnet/wiki/Install-CouchDB-1.6.1-on-Ubuntu-14.04

Comment: actually i lied, tar xvzf apache-couchdb-* doesnt work. ryan@Ryan:~$ cd apache-couchdb-*
bash: cd: apache-couchdb-*: No such file or directory
ryan@Ryan:~$ cd /tmp
ryan@Ryan:/tmp$ tar xvzf apache-couchdb-*
tar (child): apache-couchdb-1.6.1: Cannot read: Is a directory
tar (child): At beginning of tape, quitting now
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: im just going to use the other computer downstairs lol.  and hopefully i dont screw that one up to. good riddance. Sorry for any pointless frustration buddy. :D

Comment: WOOOW. GOOOT IT. Why am I typing those commands in that terminal/interface.....? Im supposed to get out of that once I've started running couchdb by shifting Cing out.... theeeeen when i type curl commands/tar stuff it works.... jajajajaj. Success! Yes, trivial indeed. I was never supposed to be in that interface/start it up that way my friend. How stupid we are. :) Time to get workin, We'll be chatting again soon Dawid, but on other topics!! jaja

Comment: I don't get where did you type that commands, but I'm glad you solved it. *We'll be chatting again soon Dawid, but on other topics!!* I hope we won't :) Good luck!

Comment: Well, once i started couch db up with sudo couchdb and it gave me the 3 welcoming lines, you know the "now you can relax" interface thing. I'm not supposed to be typing commands in that apparently(at least not for me). couchdb is supposed to be running in the "background". Infor for anyone else who may have this problem. COUCHDB SHOULD BE RUNNING IN THE BACKGROUND, and you should be typing commands with the normal $ prompts